# Is my Tweepy stream to follow specific user's Tweets set up correctly?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, reddit, praw

Hello I am fairly new with Python and I am trying to write code that will detect when a Twitter account posts with Tweepy, save the text of the Tweet as a variable, then post the Tweet to a subreddit with PRAW. I found a code online that will post to a specified subreddit and it does work so I just need to get the stream of incoming data from Tweepy. I tried to set up a stream.filter.follow(user_id) and I get no error message, but it doesn't seem to be connected to the Twitter account I made to test it. When I Tweet I don't see them coming in on my code although I thought I had it set up to print the raw_data.full_text for the Tweets. Here is my code can anyone see if there is something wrong with it. I have all the access codes and from my developer account, and I got my screen_id from a website where I put my @ in to get a number id. I have removed this sensitive info from the code.

```
import time
import tweepy
import praw

#Variables that contains the credentials to access Twitter API and REDDIT
USERNAME = 
PASSWORD = 
CLIENT_ID = 
CLIENT_SECRET = 
consumer_key = 
consumer_secret = 
access_token = 
access_secret =

#Creating stream listener
class Listener(tweepy.Stream):
    
    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        self.proccess_data(raw_data)

        return True
    
    def process_data(self, raw_data):
        print("ID: {}".format(raw_data.id))
        print(raw_data.full_text)


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code ==420:
#return False if on_data disconnects the stream
            return False

#Twitter authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
        
#Creating Stream
stream_tweet_listener = Listener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
stream_tweet = tweepy.Stream(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

#auth = api.auth, listener = stream_tweet_listener

#stream tweets
screen_id = 
stream_tweet.filter(follow = screen_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an instance of [`tweepy.Stream`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/stream.html#tweepy.Stream), which by default just logs the data received, rather than your subclass of it.

Comment: Thanks for directing me here on my other post! So I'm not exactly sure where the issue is still though?  Like instead of using tweepy.Stream should it just be Listener since that's my subclass (python noob so this could make no sense) when trying to create the stream?

Comment: Yes, `Listener` is your subclass and `stream_tweet_listener` is the instance of your subclass you've initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
    PersonId = client.get_user(username="username").data.id
    class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):

        def on_connect(self):
            print("Connected")

        def on_tweet(self, tweet):

            if tweet.author_id == PersonId : 
                print(tweet.text)

    stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token)
    #Pay attention to bearer_token recently you must tou use it
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).