# 401 error code being returned when trying to stream live Tweets from a specific account with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, reddit, praw

Anyone have any idea what could be causing the error? All my keys and tokens should be correct. I made sure to double check them. I followed the steps on how to set up the stream pretty arcuately I thought.

```
import time
import tweepy
import praw

#Variables that contains the credentials to access Twitter API and REDDIT
USERNAME = ""
PASSWORD = "!"
CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, consumer_key)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print("ID: {}".format(status.id))
        print(status.full_text)

def streamtweets():
    myStreamListener = MyStreamListener(consumer_key, consumer_secret,access_token, consumer_key)
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(consumer_key, consumer_secret,access_token, consumer_key)
    myStream.filter(follow = [''])

streamtweets()
```

Comment: Do you have Elevated access to the API, or Essential? The code you are using is trying to connect to the v1.1 API and that requires Elevated access.

Comment: I have Elevated access. I tried regenerating my codes since I had my original ones in from when I only had Essential. It still is giving me a 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing your `consumer_key` as the access token secret.

Comment: Thank you for catching that! I must have messed things up when copying and pasting stuff. I switched it and it got rid of the error message, but when I send a tweet out with my test account I see nothing on pythons end. Did I mess up my print function or am I not really connected?

Comment: [I've already answered this for your other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345987/6191255)